# In Python, how to make operation on primitive types in a loop?

Tags: python, pointers

I have the following code:

```
if isinstance(x0, float):
    x0 = int(round(x0))
if isinstance(x1, float):
    x1 = int(round(x1))
if isinstance(y0, float):
    y0 = int(round(y0))
if isinstance(y1, float):
    y1 = int(round(y1))
```

How can I do it in a nice loop, without repeating the same code 4 times?

I would maybe like something like this:

```
for x in (x0, y0, x1, y1):
    if isinstance(x, float):
        x = int(round(x))
```

Of course, this code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

With simple function:

```
x0, y0, x1, y1 = 1.0, 2.0, 3.3, 10.11

def to_round_int(n):
    return int(round(n)) if isinstance(n, float) else n

x0, y0, x1, y1 = to_round_int(x0), to_round_int(y0), to_round_int(x1), to_round_int(y1)
print(x0, y0, x1, y1)   # 1 2 3 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `globals` / `locals` dict (depends on the scope of your variables), but it's not very nice to look at:

```
x0 = x1 = y0 = y1 = 1.5

for x in ("x0", "y0", "x1", "y1"):
    if isinstance(globals()[x], float):
        globals()[x] = int(round(globals()[x]))

print(x0, x1, y0, y1)
```

Output:

```
2 2 2 2
```

Maybe you should redesign your code and use a `dict` to store your variables instead, then you can interate the dictionary keys.

Or maybe write a class with properties, where the setter already takes care of the rounding.

Or just stick to the code you already have.

Everything is better than messing with the `globals` / `locals` dictionaries.